# Jquery Autocomplete Suggestion after first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the jquery autocomplete to populate and display the menu after the first character, but my current code doesn't do this.  It works after a second character is entered and also works when you delete the entered characters.  Thoughts?

```
$("#resource").keyup(function(){
    var s = $("#resource").val();
    $( "#resource" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 0 });
    $.post("URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT_JSON_DATA_RETURNED",
        {search:s},
        function(data,status){
            if (status == 'success') {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var availableTags = [];
                if (obj.length > 0) {
                    var tags = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        var name = obj[i]['last_name']+', '+obj[i]['first_name'];
                        var u_id = obj[i]['user_id'];
                        availableTags.push( {value:name,label:name,rID:u_id} );
                    }
                }
                $("#resource").autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                      source: availableTags,
                      focus: function( event, ui ) {
                          $("#resource").val( ui.item.label );
                          $("#rID").val( ui.item.rID );
                          return false;
                      },
                      select: function( event, ui ) {
                          $("#resource").val( ui.item.label );
                          $("#rID").val( ui.item.rID );
                          return false;
                      }
                });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: can you create a plunkr so we can help. http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Sorry to ask, but: are you sure that's not because of the server-side code? Do any requests go to server when one inputs just a single character?

Comment: is the return really big? your server could time out..